# Solving a problem using multiple threads using CLP

Tags: parallel-computing, software, linear-programming

Is it possible to run Clp on multiple threads using Julia and JuMP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Clp, I assume that you're referring to the linear programming code that is part of the COIN-OR project:

http://www.coin-or.org/Clp/

Clp's primal and dual simplex codes aren't multithreaded so even if you call Clp from within a multithreaded program in Julia, each LP will be solved by a single thread.  It is possible to use the primal-dual interior point method in Clp with a threaded sparse Cholesky factorization routine.

In general, it has proven to be extremely difficult to get an efficient implementation of the simplex method in parallel.  Parallel implementations of primal-dual interior point method have been more successful primarily because the major work in each iteration of the primal-dual method is the Cholesky factorization of a large sparse matrix and considerable progress has been made on doing those factorizations in parallel.